# Migrating hibernate from 5.6.7 into 6.2.6 . then after updating any data giving "hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist"

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using MySQL, and I think MySQL does not support sequences. So, how can I resolve this problem? I have tried adding the 'hibernate_sequence' table, but I am still getting an error. The error message is as follows:
'Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
TableStructure:158 - could not read a hi value
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer hibernate versions like 5.6.15.Final, hibernate_sequence table is generated which contains next_val column whose value is the next value to be auto incremented in primary key columns. This is somehow problematic when working with multiple tables with auto incremented columns.

To prevent hibernate_sequence table from being generated, in your entities change

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

to

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: I have already using this strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY . but still i am facing same issue

Comment: Have changed strategy to GenerationType.IDENTITY in all entities? After changes, have tried to clean & build project before running it?